# D3 - update data in chart with out redrawing svg - enter, exit

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/WsE6zhIUY9ictTtOTU1W?p=preview

Its a stacked bar chart using D3 in angular 4

I have an update button that updates the data in the chart.

I don't to want redraw the whole chart but just update the bars.

The button calls the drawChart that just creates the bars.

I have a console.log here that shows the data is getting updated when the button is clicked.

```
private drawChart(data:any){
      console.log(data);
        this.layersBar = this.layersBarArea.selectAll('.layer')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .classed('layer', true)
            .style('fill', (d:any,i:any)=>{
                return this.colors[i]
            });

        this.x.domain(this.stackedChart.map((d:any)=>{
            return d.date
        }));

        this.y.domain([0, +d3.max(this.stackedSeries, function(d:any){
            return d3.max(d, (d:any)=>{
                return d[1]
            })
        })]);

        this.layersBar.selectAll('rect')
          .exit()
          .remove()
            .data((d:any)=>{
                return d;
            })
            .enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('y', (d:any)=>{
                return this.y(d[1])
            })
            .attr('x', (d:any, i:any)=>{
                return this.x(d.data.date)
            })
            .attr('width', this.x.bandwidth())
            .attr('height', (d:any, i:any)=>{
                return this.y(d[0]) - this.y(d[1]);
            })
    }
}
```

I'm using `.exit() .remove()` before the `enter()` I thought this would handle removing the old data.

I think this is the last part of my D3 to get this working.

==========================================

Update

In this plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/9zVKStEPuwoHlbrWgLlV?p=preview

I can load the new data but cant remove the old data, how do I remove the old bars.

==========================================

Update

So I have it working in this plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/oFky8JrD5u90qOuZQlk1?p=preview

I have simpler swapped the position of the .remove and .exit

Does anyone know if this the correct way to do this. I havent seen this in any examples

```
private drawChart(data:any){

    this.layersBar = this.layersBarArea.selectAll('.layer')
      .remove()
      .exit()
      .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .classed('layer', true)
        .style('fill', (d:any,i:any)=>{
            return this.colors[i]
        });

    this.x.domain(this.stackedChart.map((d:any)=>{
        return d.date
    }));

    this.y.domain([0, +d3.max(this.stackedSeries, function(d:any){
        return d3.max(d, (d:any)=>{
            return d[1]
        })
    })]);

    this.layersBar.selectAll('rect')

        .data((d:any)=>{
            return d;
        })
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('y', (d:any)=>{
            return this.y(d[1])
        })
        .attr('x', (d:any, i:any)=>{
            return this.x(d.data.date)
        })
        .attr('width', this.x.bandwidth())
        .attr('height', (d:any, i:any)=>{
            return this.y(d[0]) - this.y(d[1]);
        })
}
```